# Fetch alternate emails using facebook php api

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I was wanted to use the facebook php sdk to extact all relevant details of the user who logs in to my app . I am aware that this can be done by the facebook->api('/me') API .

I am trying the fetch the email address of the user . Besides this i also want to fetch alternate email addresses of the user .

I am aware that some people have tried doing this in the past but facebook api does not support fetching alternate email addresses . Does this still hold true . ? I dont see any document that suggests that the feature has been implemented recently . want to be doubly sure .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry Dude, but Facebook doesn't provide the Alternate Email Address with the user object. Here are the fields that are accessible.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/

Alternate Email Address is never to be disclosed since it is used to retrieve forgotten passwords and many more other options.

Comment: thanks @vijay . I agree . i went thorough the above link carefully and it does seem that they dont support fetching alternate email addresses .